# How do I show these sets of maps are integral domains?

Tags: functions, ring-theory, integral-domain

So I've been given these two rings:

$R = Map(\mathbb{R, R})$ which I need to prove is **NOT** an integral domain and

$R/I$ where $R$ is defined as above and $I = \{f \in R | f(1) = 0\}$ which I need to prove **IS** an integral domain.

So what I've determined so far is that in $R$ the zero element is $f(x)=0$ since its always $0$ so anything added to it will always be unchanged. I was thinking that I could use a piecewise function like

$g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 0 \mbox{ if } x<0\\ 0\text{ if }x >0 \end{array}\right.$

That leaves $g(x) = 0$ undefined but its zero in every other way so despite not being the zero element so any other map $h$ multiplied with it will almost be $0$ at any point. I'm just not sure because $g(x) = 0$ is undefined so $(gh)(x) = 0$ will be undefined, not $0$. I'm not sure if that's enough to show $gh = 0$ where $g\neq{0}$.

Moreover, I'm not sure why the quotient ring $R/I$ is an integral domain even though $R$ isn't.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Consider $g(x)=0$ if $ x<0$ and $1$ otherwise and $h(x)=1$ if $x<0$ and $0$ otherwise

Comment: For the second part you can look at the homomorphism $g:R\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(f)=f(1)$, for $f\in R$. The kernel of $g$ is $I$. Therefore, $R/I$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. Alternatively, you can do a direct proof. Assume that $fg+I=(f+I)(g+I)=0+I$. Then $fg\in I$. This means that $f(1)g(1)=0$. This implies that either $f(1)=0$ or $g(1)=0$. In the first case $f\in I$, while in the second case $g\in I$. Therefore, either $f+I$ is the zero in $R/I$ or $g+I$ is the zero in $R/I$.

Comment: You can't leave g(0) undefined.  Map($\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}$) means it has to be defined everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

For part 1, try to design two non-zero functions $f \neq 0$ and $g \neq 0$ such that $fg = 0$. E.g., what can you do if $f(x) = 0$ when $x = 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ otherwise.

For part 2, what can you say about the mapping $R \to \Bbb{R}$ that maps $f$ to $f(1)$? Is it well-defined, one-to-one, onto, a homomorphism? If it is a homomorphism, what is its kernel?